# Spring authentication page change

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-web

Sorry about the poor title, I didn't know how to put it in words.

My issue is that I created using Spring Initializr a project with:

- Spring Web
- Spring Security
- Spring Actuator
- Spring JPA

  ```
  <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

When I map an URL and try to access it I get this nice login form:

[login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Ngz.png)

But when I override the security with

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

I get this ugly login form

[ugly login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Ct5.png)

I guess is because when overriding the config, something is changing which login form Spring uses or I am using Spring security wrong.

Can someone tell me why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: I just removed the @EnableWebSecurity and now the application still uses the actuator login form. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The first nice login form belongs to your browser. If you try with different browsers, you will see different results. What happens is that when your browser requests the URL of your application, your application responds with an unauthorized code and then, your browser asks you to provide credentials to retry the request.

The ugly login form is Spring's default. You can stylize it however you want. You can see [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) or [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/guides/form.html) examples to get you started. You'll need to add some CSS.

The default implementation of the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` which you didn't override when you extended the class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` looks like this:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("Using default configure(HttpSecurity). If subclassed this will potentially override subclass configure(HttpSecurity).");

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin().and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

That `.formLogin()` is where you get the ugly login form.